# Replacing values in a dataframe - why doesn't it work?

Tags: r, replace, na

```
for(i in 1:nrow(survey)){
    for(j in 1:ncol(survey)){
        if(survey[i,j] < 1 | survey[i,j] >10){
            survey[i,j] <- "NA"
        }
    }
}
```

I have this data set:

```
survey <- data.frame("q1" = c(5, 3, 2, 7, 11, 5),
                     "q2" = c(4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 2),
                     "q3" = c(2, 1, 4, 2, 9, 10),
                     "q4" = c(2, 5, 2, 5, 4, 2),
                     "q5" = c(1, 4, -20, 2, 11, 2))
```

I would like to replace all the numbers smaller than 1 and larger than 10, so I wrote the r code above. And I got this when running the code:

```
q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
1  5  4  2  2  1
2  3  2  1  5  4
3  2  2  4  2 NA
4  7  5  2  5 NA
5 NA  5  9  4 NA
6 NA  2 10  2 NA
```

Why it does not work? What do I miss in the code? Could anyone advise me, please?

Comment: You don't assign an `NA` but a string containing `"NA"`. This changes the type of your data into a character and messing up the `<` / `>` comparison.

Answer (score 1):

It could be much easier, try something like this:

```
survey[survey > 10 | survey < 1] <- NA

survey
  q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
1  5  4  2  2  1
2  3  2  1  5  4
3  2  2  4  2 NA
4  7  5  2  5  2
5 NA  5  9  4 NA
6  5  2 10  2  2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that!

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use the set function of `is.na` i.e. `is.na<-`

```
is.na(survey) <- survey > 10|survey < 1
survey
  q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
1  5  4  2  2  1
2  3  2  1  5  4
3  2  2  4  2 NA
4  7  5  2  5  2
5 NA  5  9  4 NA
6  5  2 10  2  2
```

---

The main issue as mentioned in the comments is `"NA"` is character string.  If we do an assignment to an element in a column that is already a numeric one with character, the whole column is converted to `character`.  Instead, use `NA`

```
for(i in 1:nrow(survey)){
     for(j in 1:ncol(survey)){
         if(survey[i,j] < 1 | survey[i,j] >10){
             survey[i,j] <- NA
         }
     }
 }
 
survey
  q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
1  5  4  2  2  1
2  3  2  1  5  4
3  2  2  4  2 NA
4  7  5  2  5  2
5 NA  5  9  4 NA
6  5  2 10  2  2
```

The comparison operators works differently for `character` values i.e.

```
> "10" > "1"
[1] TRUE
> "10" > "5"
[1] FALSE
```